# How to link a scene from a file which contains Animation Nodes tree?

Tags: animation-nodes

The problem is when I link a scene from a file which contains Animation Nodes tree the linked scene will not contain the node tree.
Here is the original file content:

[image: Sample scene with Animation Nodes tree]

And here is the linked file:

[image: Linked file with Animation Nodes tree]

As we can see, the node tree has gone, so it meas I get a "static view" from the original scene. I can no longer edit the nodes and I don't have the animation managed with Animation Nodes.

Is there a way to link scene with Animation Nodes properly? 
Or is there some kind of solution or workaround?

Comment: Currently AN nodetrees can only be appended. linking operation doesn't work yet.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to implement that feature at all? Can we expect that in a future release? Read somewhere pynodes have limitations...

Comment: Not sure, maybe you can discuss it [here](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/new) with Jacques.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Just to mention: I baked the animation onto the objects below the _Animation Nodes Object Container_ and it worked in the scene where I liked.

Comment: Cool and yes, it could be a workaround anyway.  :)